# Can't install packages anymore because of raspberrypi-kernel failure: bad dkms conf file

Tags: kernel, apt

I somehow messed something up with my Raspbian; it's a fairly new install on a RPi 3B+.
When I run `sudo apt update` and the `sudo apt upgrade` I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up raspberrypi-kernel (1:1.20210831-3~buster) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 5.10.60+ /boot/kernel.img
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 5.10.60+ /boot/kernel.img
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
dkms.conf: Error! No 'DEST_MODULE_LOCATION' directive specified.
dkms.conf: Error! No 'PACKAGE_NAME' directive specified.
dkms.conf: Error! No 'PACKAGE_VERSION' directive specified.
Error! Bad conf file.
File:
does not represent a valid dkms.conf file.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 8
dpkg: error processing package raspberrypi-kernel (--configure):
 installed raspberrypi-kernel package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 raspberrypi-kernel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried several solutions from other internet posts but none are working for me (apt clean, apt install -f, dist-upgrade)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Wipe the card and reimage it.

Comment: Your "including but not limited to" is pretty meaningless: it suggests that whatever solution people may post, you have already tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Run `dkms status` to see which dynamic kernel modules you have installed. Then either reinstall those modules if you need them, or remove with

```
 sudo dkms remove <module>/<ver> --all
```

e.g.

```
 sudo dkms remove anbox-binder/1 --all
```